# API request for every value in array and return it

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I have an array with lots of games that have unique id. I need to make a request for every id to retrieve minutes played for that specific game.

So my array looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Team 1 vs Team 2'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Team 1 vs Team 2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Team 1 vs Team 2'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Team 1 vs Team 2'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Team 1 vs Team 2'
  }
]
```

I have been trying to forEach through the array, make a request with Axios to the API and then retrieve the data.

The Api looks like this. It is alot more, just narrowed it down. there is an image below with more description:

```
{
  event: {
   123123: {
    id: 1,
    elapsed: {
      1: {
        elapsed: '45'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The elapsed key is unique, for some reason, so I am using a Object.keys to "find" it.

My code:

```
array.forEach(game => {
  axios.get(`http://example.com/${game.id}`)
  .then(res => {
    let time = 0;
    Object.keys(res.data.event).map(eventId) => { //the eventId is the id for the event, in this case 123123.
      Object.keys(res.data.event[eventId].elapsed).map(el => {
        time = res.data.event[eventId].elapsed[el].elapsed; //el is the key-id for the elapsed object.
      )};
    )};
    return time;
  });
});
```

This does not work, I just get undefined. What am I doing wrong? And yes, the API looks like a mess. I have images below in case that will help you. It's a JSON file, I just have a JSON Formatter:

[image: Most confusing API]

EDIT: Edited my code

Comment: you're... not doing anything with the result. I see where you're mapping the object keys and what not, but you never actually used the result of all that work.

Comment: Alright. I did it another way retrieve the data, if you watch the edit. I define a variable before, and inside my map-function I set the my variable to the elapsed, and at the end I return. that does not work either

Comment: that return still doesn't do anything. You returned to the .then(), but you're not doing anything with the result past that.

Comment: Should I set a return before the axios function as well? Should that be it? `return axios.get('https://example.com');`

Comment: That would help. If you then converted the .forEach to a .map and passed the resulting array to a promise.all(), you would then be able to use .then on that to get all of the results.

Comment: Alright. I think I solved it. I remade the code and made it to a async function instead. It solved my issue